# Show csv data in table using python

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, treeview

How to show the CSV file data manually in Tkinter treeview?

Here I am trying to show the CSV file data using treeview. To insert data manually in tkinter used this command:

```
tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[sorted(j for j in range(k[1]))]),tag = 'gray')
```

Using this I am getting parentheses on GUI and timestamp column has separated.
when using

```
tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[0],val[1],val[2],val[3],val[4],val[5],val[6],val[7],val[8],val[9],val[10],val[11],val[12],val[13],val[14],val[15]),tag = 'gray')
```

I am not getting any parentheses and timestamp column is not separated.

Why this is happening? Please suggest.

Thanks and regards.
[image: Result_image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1500x200")

data = []
file = ('E:\\PYTHON\\data transfer\\shiva new\\100lines.csv')
csv_data = pd.read_csv(file)
k = csv_data.shape
print(k)
values = csv_data.values
columns = csv_data.columns
frame = Frame(root,height=500,width=500)
frame.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns = (sorted(col for col in range(1,k[1]+2))),height = 2, show = "headings")
print(tree['columns'])
tree.pack(side = 'left',fill='both',expand=1)

scroll1 = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
scroll1.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll1.set)

scroll2 = Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
scroll2.pack(side = 'bottom', fill = 'x')

tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll2.set)

for i in range(1,k[1]+2):
    print(i)
    tree.heading(i, text=i)#(k for k in range(k[1]))
    tree.column(i, width = 80)


for i,val in enumerate(values):

    i1 = i%2
    if (i1==0):

        tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[sorted(j for j in range(k[1]))]),tag = 'gray')

        #tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[0],val[1],val[2],val[3],val[4],val[5],val[6],val[7],val[8],val[9],val[10],val[11],val[12],val[13],val[14],val[15]),tag = 'gray')
    else:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[0],val[1],val[2],val[3],val[4],val[5],val[6],val[7],val[8],val[9],val[10],val[11],val[12],val[13],val[14],val[15]))
        #tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[sorted(j for j in range(k[1]))]))
tree.tag_configure('gray', background='#cccccc')        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first one assigns `ndarray` to `values`, whereas the second one assigns `tuple` to `values`.  Try changing first one to `values=tuple(val[...])`.

Comment: May i see the output of: `print(val[sorted(j for j in range(k[1]))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you acw1668.
using the tuple problem is solved.

Now how can i insert row numbers?

Comment: Add `text=i+1` in `tree.insert(...)` and change `show='headings'` to `show='tree headings'` when creating the `Treeview`.

Comment: Thank you. How to seperate each row with lines? now I am using tags to seperate lines like in result image.